# Trying to multiply and make another row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I make another row called 'Sum'), which contains the sum of for each order line (quantity, multiplied by price). in Pandas. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

#Make own path to file
files = Path("").rglob("*.csv")

df =[pd.read_csv(file,index_col=0) for file in files ] 

df = pd.concat(df)

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df.dropna(subset = ["Order ID"], inplace=True)

df['Price Each'].astype('int')
df['Quantity Ordered'].astype('int')

#df['Sum']= df['Quantity Ordered'].astype(int) * df['Price Each'].astype(int)

df.assign('Sum'== df['Quantity Ordered'] * df['Price Each'])

print(df)
```

[image: The DataFrame]

I get this back: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11.95'

I have tried to use

```
df['Price Each'].astype('int')
df['Quantity Ordered'].astype('int')
df['Sum']= df['Quantity Ordered'].astype(int) * df['Price Each'].astype(int)
```

But I got the same Error as before.
Is there a way to to what i intend.

Comment: Your data have decimals, convert to `float`, not `int`. What is your expected output from `int('11.95')`?

Comment: @G.Anderson with just decimals `.astype(int)` should work, I think OP has `nans` in the respective columns. Otherwise `df['Sum']= df['Quantity Ordered'].astype(int) * df['Price Each'].astype(int) ` this should work

Comment: @MuhammadHassan the error is pretty clear, `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11.95'` means that you can't convert a string with a `.` in it to an `int`. If it were already stored as a float, it would defo work, though. Otherwise, if it were a nan problem, it would have said `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: Oh got it, thanks. I didn't know that you can't convert a `string` with a `.` in it to an `int`

Comment: @G.Anderson post that as an answer,

Comment: Voted to close as typo/not reproducible, the error is self-explanatory enough to make an answer superfluous IMO